# Trying to use a variable in jQuery Nth-child

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I know there's one or two similar questions on here but the answers provided don't solve my problem. 
I am creating a random number, then I want to highlight a particular element that is the nth-child (using that random number)

Here is the code, it works if I use a regular number but highlights every child if I use the variable.

```
c = $(".slideList li").length;
rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * c);
$('.slideList > li:nth-child(" + rn + ")').addClass('on');
$('.testBoxesContain > div:nth-child(" + rn + ")').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 5):

Quotes mix-up:

```
$('.slideList > li:nth-child(' + rn + ')')
```

not

```
$('.slideList > li:nth-child(" + rn + ")')
```

Comment: Please accept an answer if you are happy this is the solution. (Refer to SO FAQs if you're new to the system).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the same kind of quote to end the string and start another.

```
$('.slideList > li:nth-child(' + rn + ')').addClass('on');
```

This ends the string, concatenates `rn`, and then concatenates the rest the string.